# Secure Laravel website hosting

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I developed a website using laravel and on my web hoster I have not find the `public` directory so , I changed the `server.php`

*From*

```
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

*To*

```
require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';
```

and I moved all the contents of the `public` folder in the root and the website works very well BUT the problem is when I put for example `http://mywebsite.com/.env` I can show the content of `.env` so my site is not protected.

**The Question :**

How can I protect my files and directories ?

*Example of structure I want:*

```
index.php
.htaccess
favicon.ico
img/
css/
js/
laravel/
      app/
      bootstrap/
      database/
      config/
      storage/
     .env
     server.php
     ...
```

Content of the root of my site => the public folder content

`laravel` directory => the other directories and files

Comment: Don't edit the the server.php file. Just create a directory called public

Comment: don't works because my web hoster does not contain a public folder

Comment: Then create one yourself !

Comment: If your host is using cPanel and its an addon domain, add your Laravel install in the addon domain's directory and then change the addon domain's directory to the public directory of the Laravel installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place everything back in the public folder and revert the changes to server.php. Then in your top level directory add a .htaccess file with the code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You could also just symlink to the public folder, I had some problems with .htaccess before that's why I prefer symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't remove the public folder. You could either add a .htaccess file or create a symlink that links to /public, both approaches should work but I usually go with the symlink.

In case your laravel installation folder is called "laravel" and your server expects "html" to be the folder with your website in it you should do something like this:

```
ln -s laravel/public html
```

Comment: Just a note - quite a few shared web hosts don't allow shell access.

Comment: That's true but if he's builiding a laravel app I expect him to have shell access, otherwise it would be a real pain to do things like Migrations etc.